# PHP white screen on error

Tags: php

I'm getting a white screen every time a PHP application drops an error.
I checked php.ini and error_reporting  =  E_ALL and display_errors = On
Also I checked with the php_info() function and error_reporting is set to 6135 which is correct.

I already tried adding:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
to my index.php but didn't worked.

Also I don't have any custom error handler function.
Does anybody what else can cause a white screen in PHP?

by the way, it's not caused by an unclosed bracket neither, if I intentionally leave an error in the index.php it is displayed.

But when I try to load a heavy page, the white screen is displayed. I'm using the same MySql server for other applications without problems.

Comment: I think that the reason may be that the application is too heavy and it's making Apache to fail without loging anything

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart IIS/Apache after making those changes?

Answer (score 0):

maybe take a look at error_log ?

Comment: I just did and nothing is logged

Answer (score 0):

maybe memory leak or max execution time are the problem .. try increasing them in php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 80M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

Comment: thanks, I already modified those and didn't fixed it

Comment: so Try looking to the apache error_log may be it could be helpful.